# How to protect caddy API endpoints? (configuration ones)

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

How do i protect configutation caddy server endpoints?

https://caddyserver.com/docs/api it seems anyone can curl into the server and run the config api there.

Is there any standard? Can it be done through some delegated auth?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the access via different options which are documented in [JSON Config Structure › admin](https://caddyserver.com/docs/json/admin/) documentation.